# Data Annotation with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, xsd, wsdl

I am creating a WSDl for a client where they will send request and we will do response.Request contains either phone-number or location or both ie at least one is required.WHat is the best way i can enforce restriction here.I heard like we can use dataanotations which i have used in MVC.I tried in WCF, but when i checked in WSDL by right click ->view in browser i cannot see the restion like minoccurs=1 or range which we were seeing in XSD.So my question is Do i need to create seperate XSD and validate the request or do i need to add dataanotations.Can any body tell me some simple steps which i can follow.Here is what i have tried

```
[DataMember]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
        public string Phonenumber
        {
            get
            {
                return this.phonenumber;
            }
            set
            {
                this.phonenumber = value;
            }
        }
        /// <remarks/>
        /// 
        [DataMember]
                [DataMember]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name Required")]
        public string Location
        {
            get
            {
                return this.location;
            }
            set
            {
                this.location = value;
            }
        }
```

and in wsdl i can see like

```
<xs:element name="Phonenumber" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Location" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

WCF does not understand the `[Required]` attribute (or other attributes from the data annotations namespace). If you want a data member to be required, you can set the `IsRequired` property in the attribute:

```
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Phonenumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phonenumber;
        }
        set
        {
            this.phonenumber = value;
        }
    }
    /// <remarks/>
    /// 
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Location
    {
        get
        {
            return this.location;
        }
        set
        {
            this.location = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: i heard like we can use annotations like we were used in MVC.I hope there will be a way like http://rahulrraj.blogspot.ae/2012/03/wcf-error-handling-using.html.But i am not sure like if this can be used for a scenario like wsdl is generated and and gave to a remote client